# Text appears at the bottom of row when image is image inserted in the next column

Tags: tables, graphics

I want to use latex to make PDF for all figures. Please see the code. The image is inserted but "100" on the left column appears at the bottom of the row. How do I align that to top or center of the row?
Thanks a lot
Jay

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}



\begin{document}
\textbf{Title} \hfill \textit{Author}
\smallskip
\hrule

\begin{tabular}{ |>{\centering}m{1.1in}| p{1.6in}|}
\hline

Drug Conc (ug/ml) & Image \\

100 & \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{100.jpg} \\


\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX Stack Exchange!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.